# 3D shape with orthogonal projections that form circles of the same radius.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, 3d

Let's say you have a 3D shape. The side view, front view, and top view of the shape are all circles of the same radius. Does the shape have to be a sphere, or is it possible that it could be another shape?

Answer (score 2):

Take 3 very thin circular disks of the same radius; a red one, a green one, and a blue one. Then put them together so that   the side view, the front view, and the top view be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One variation of [Steinmetz solid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html) is the intersection of three mutually-perpendicular cylinders.

[image]
[image]
[image]

(Image credit: Weisstein, Eric W. "Steinmetz Solid." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html)